# TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__' with on create methode

Tags: python, model, odoo

i'm trying to get a specific Prefix field named 'Nom' from the model souches 'Souches.souche' then i'm giving the methom a search parameters from a selecion field name 'Souche_sale'. 
the final resulat is to add the concatunate the char value  called 'prefix'. 
Here is the code caption

```
def create(self, cr, user, vals, context=None):
    context = context or {}
    if ('name' not in vals) or (vals.get('name') in ('/', False)):
        ptype_id = vals.get('picking_type_id', context.get('default_picking_type_id', False))
        sequence_id = self.pool.get('stock.picking.type').browse(cr, user, ptype_id, context=context).sequence_id.id
        stock_prefixes = self.pool.get[('souches.souche','Nom','=',vals.get('Souche_stock'))].browse(cr, uid, ids) 
        prefix = [x.Pre_BL for x in stock_prefixes][0]

        vals['origin'] =  str(prefix) + self.pool.get('ir.sequence').next_by_id(cr, user, sequence_id, context=context)
```

anyone could help with this
 thanks and regards.

Comment: Could you edit the traceback into your question?

Answer (score 2):

Exception in this line?

```
stock_prefixes = self.pool.get[('souches.souche','Nom','=',vals.get('Souche_stock'))].browse(cr, uid, ids)
```

`.get` is instancemethod. You must call it like self.pool.get(...), but you tried to call it with `[]`: self.pool.get[..]